# after run AsyncTask class, next activity return nullpointexception

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is my AsyncTask class

```
private class UpdatingNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        webservice.UpdateAllNews();
        webservice.updateallCatNews();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
```

i call it by

```
UpdatingNewsupdate = new UpdatingNews();
        update.execute();
```

It does excecute. Then i want to check the status of this task has finish or not when i click button so i check like this.

```
if (update.getStatus().toString()
                            .equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED.toString())) {
                        toast = Toast.makeText(Main_FormNewUser.this,
                                "Thanks for fill in our survey form!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                                | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        name = nametext.getText().toString();
                        email = emailtext.getText().toString();
                        webservice.InsertSurvey(name, email, ages, genders,
                                jobs, salaries, interesting);
                        webservice.insertFormSubmit(1);

                        startActivity(new Intent(Main_FormNewUser.this,
                                Main_AllLatestNews.class));
                        finish();
                    }
```

After i clicked, it will start Main_AllLatestNews.class but with NullPointerException.

I try not use AsyncTask and return me no error, i got no idea why i call AsyncTask it will give me error?

Comment: What line is the NPE on?

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand the basics of AsyncTask Check this blog. [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html)  or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

You have not accept the return from doInBackground() in onPostExecute(String result)

doInBackground() return the result to onPostExecute. So you have to update the values or the UI that you want here in onPostExecute only.

Comment: @som_rout although it is true that you can't perform UI actions in doInBackground(), you can change data sets in the doInBackground.  It seems like that is what he is doing here

Comment: @mikeisrael you are right. may be this methods webservice.UpdateAllNews();
webservice.updateallCatNews(); might not update the values.

Comment: it does, which is downloading online database to local database, but after finish then return error when next activity started

Comment: @AlanLai if you want any help put up your logcat.

Comment: the nullpointerexception occur at getting the size of a list
`list.size()`

Answer (score 0):

how about use onPostExecute like this way

add boolean value to determine whether AsyncTask is end or not

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    check = true;
}


//if (update.getStatus().toString().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED.toString())) {
if(check){
                    toast = Toast.makeText(Main_FormNewUser.this,
                            "Thanks for fill in our survey form!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                            | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    name = nametext.getText().toString();
                    email = emailtext.getText().toString();
                    webservice.InsertSurvey(name, email, ages, genders,
                            jobs, salaries, interesting);
                    webservice.insertFormSubmit(1);

                    startActivity(new Intent(Main_FormNewUser.this,
                            Main_AllLatestNews.class));
                    finish();
                }
```